# GetAsyncKeyState - checking most significant bit in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to detect when a key is actively pressed using GetAsyncKeyState (since I want to make use of the async check as well).

Masking the most signficant bit and checking for a non-zero value should do the trick to my understanding, however some users of my software are finding that random key presses are being detected that they have not pressed, is this an issue with my method or is there some factor I am unaware of?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey);

public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys vKey)
{
    return ((GetAsyncKeyState(vKey) & 0x8000) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to test for the returned value being negative:

```
return ((GetAsyncKeyState(vKey) < 0);
```

But your code does the same thing. So I guess your problem lies elsewhere.