# C# GetAsyncKeyState not working properly

Tags: c#

I have this code that I made where it gets the keystate of left click and then if its true, it makes "MemeKey" set to true else it makes "MemeKey" set to false. For some reason its giving me this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'short' to 'bool'

Here is my code:

```
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01))
        {
            MemeKey = true;
        }
```

This post is NOT a duplicate of [GetAsyncKeyState - checking most significant bit in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336213/getasynckeystate-checking-most-significant-bit-in-c-sharp) because it says in that answer, "But your code does the same thing. So I guess your problem lies elsewhere." and his question was never solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetAsyncKeyState - checking most significant bit in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336213/getasynckeystate-checking-most-significant-bit-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @RaymondChen yes but that one was never answered.

Comment: I see an answer [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27336225/902497).

Comment: @RaymondChen It says: "But your code does the same thing. So I guess your problem lies elsewhere."

Comment: The answer shows how to call the function correctly, which is the problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

GetAsyncKeyState returns a SHORT in the windows API, and I'm guessing your p/Invoke declaration preserves that.  You are trying to reference it like a boolean.  This is trying to cast the short as a boolean as the exception states.

Instead, you need to test if the most significant bit of the resulting short is set, to determine if the key is currently pressed:

```
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) & 0x8000 == 0x8000) 
{
    MemeKey = true;
}
```

Comment: now it gives me this error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'

Comment: What does your p/invoke declaration of `GetAsyncKeyState` look like?  You might need to use System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F1, etc. instead of 0x01 if you have it declared that way.  The WinAPI call takes an int, so if it is declared as an int in your p/invoke declaration, then `0x01` is correct.

Comment: Ok, now I have no errors but it doesnt even pick up my left click

Comment: NVM I FIXED IT IM SUCH A RETARD

Comment: Now the memekey only activates if one of my keyboard keys is pressed, so now I need to press one of my keyboard keys and also the left click... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: forgot to tag u so u can see it